# Powershell not reading certain values from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am currently modifying our new user script to read from a .csv file to create the account automatically. Currently it functions as far as creating the account is concerned. However it is not putting the user in the correct OU/assigning the correct groups.

I have narrowed this down to powershell not reading the values for 3 of the fields in the csv.

When I run:

```
$objExcel = Import-csv C:\New_users.csv

ForEach ($User in $objExcel)
{
$firstName = $User.FirstName
$lastName = $User.Surname
$fullname = $firstname + " " + $lastName
$employeeID = $User.EmployeeID
$jobtitle = $User.JobTitle
$location = $User.Location
$getOU = $User.AccessLevel
$EXCH = $User.Mailbox

Write-Host $firstName
Write-Host $lastName
Write-Host $fullname
Write-Host $employeeID
Write-Host $jobtitle
Write-Host $location
Write-Host $getOU
Write-Host $EXCH
}
```

It returns:

```
Test
Person
Test Person
123456

Rochester
```

This is what my csv currently looks like:

```
FirstName,Surname,EmployeeID,JobTitle,Location,AccessLevel,Mailbox
Test,Person,123456,ECO,Rochester,ECO,N
```

As you can see it is not returning any values for JobTitle, AccessLevel or Mailbox.

These values are needed to decide the username format, the groups they are added to, which OU they are placed in to and whether or not to create an email account.

If anyone could shed some light as to why these values are null it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this here; pasting your CSV into a file here, and then pasting your `ForEach` block into the console, I get values for all of the fields.

Comment: If you call $objExcel right after the import, What do you see? I ran your code exactly as written and had no problems with it. Same for the csv you provided.